# can we map multiple annoter to props.setProperty("tokensregex.matchedExpressionsAnnotationKey",com.demo.UcpAnnoter$CreditAvailableByAnnotation");

Tags: stanford-nlp

Can we mapped two/multiple annotation to `tokensregex.matchedExpressionsAnnotationKey`

Sample code:

```
props.setProperty("tokensregex.matchedExpressionsAnnotationKey","com.demo.SampleAnnoter$MyMatchedExpressionAnnotation");
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can only provide one class for that field.